# How to change the screen resolution on an Ubuntu VM

Tags: virtualbox, resolution, xorg

I've installed Ubuntu 10.10 on VirtualBox and I can't change resolution It looks terrible.

How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install guest additions provided by Virtualbox in virtual Ubuntu 10.10 machine.
I assume that you have windows machine as a host, so I can't help you how to put the virtualbox guest additions to virtual drive. But probably you'll need to do that through storage settings for that virtual machine. 
Once you did that, you'll see a mounted CD on Ubuntu desktop. Then go to terminal:

```
cd /media
ls
```

That will give you the list of directories, you'll see one that belongs to mounted virtualbox additions CD, to go inside:

```
cd the_name_of_that_directory
```

Once inside that directory just write:

```
sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

And that should install it. Reboot and you'll be able to setup the resolution. 
P.S. 10.10 is already an old version.